# MySql command for selecting entries in a field which has certain sub strings at specific locations?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to select entries in a field which has certain sub strings at specific locations??

For an example, say I have an 'ID' column in my table which contains

```
OP/13/MAY/009,
OP/13/JAN/002,
FM/14/JAN/001,
FM/13/FEB/008,
FG/13/DEC/007,
```

I want to select only the entries which begins with 'FM' and 7,8,9 characters equal 'FEB'.

Is there a mySQL query to do this?. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please have a look at the LIKE command and regular expressions

Comment: Yes, there is, and it is called 'substring'. You can also use LIKE and REGEXP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `LIKE` statement will consider `_` as any character while `%` as any amount of any characters.

```
select id from table
where id like "FM____FEB%"
```

Answer (score 0):

E.g.:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(my_string,'/',3),'/',-1) MMM FROM my_table;


+-----+
| MMM |
+-----+
| DEC |
| FEB |
| JAN |
| JAN |
| MAY |
+-----+
```

Comment: Just FYI, this answer got auto-flagged for length/content. Remember to try and add a little explanation to avoid getting deleted.